# Loading webViews using iCarousel doesnt scroll when swiping on centre View

Tags: ios, uiwebview, carousel, icarousel

I am using `iCarousel` library to load `UIWebView`s. I am unable to scroll the `carousel` when i swipe on the center view. When i swipe outside the centre View, I do not have any problem in scrolling. I do not have the similar problem when i use `UIImageView`. I am facing this problem only for `UIWebview`. I am using the below code to create the web views in `viewForItemAtIndex` method.

```
-(UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel1 viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view {
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, 100, 100)];
    return webView;
}
```

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Should the web view content be scrollable?

Comment: No. I have tried enabling and disabing scroll for webViews. but Still iam facing the same issue.

Comment: webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled=NO;

Comment: Did you try `userInteractionEnabled = NO`

Comment: that doesnt work too. But i want userInteraction to be enable for WebView since I am rendering some html charts on it which would require user interaction.

Comment: UIWebViews have gestures for going forward and backwards through the history, you should disable these properties, so that those gesture controls do not override the carousel, canGoBack and canGoForward are the properties you should set to NO on a UIWebView

Comment: canGoBack and canGoForward are read only properties. Advise how can i use them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a gesture recognizer issue preventing the carousel pan gesture from working. It seems you can't set your controller as the delegate of the `webView.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer` so, you will need to edit the carousel because it doesn't make the `panGestureRecognizer` it uses publicly available. Edit it to add your controller as the delegate and then you can return `YES` from `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:`. Alternatively, you can hide this inside the carousel by making it the delegate of its own gesture...

Comment: I mean editing of carousel.Should I need to override any carousel method?Please clarify this to me.

Comment: Not override, add a new method to allow access to the internal gesture, or edit a method to set the delegate of the internal gesture and implement a delegate method

Comment: It did work for me and thanks for helping me second time with carousel.But I have one more issue.I need button action on the Carousel page with Webview so that I can go to the respective page indeed.But when I add button over webview then iCarousel is not scrolling similarly when I add button below webview the button action is not called.What should I do please suggest?

Comment: @Imran, create a new question and show the code you're using to create the web view and button

Comment: I have added the question.Please see.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079646/trouble-in-creating-webview-and-button-on-each-icarousal-view